# Is there a recommended and/or compatible antivirus software and/or tool available for Tor Browser Bundle

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, windows, tails, malware

Specifically, for window OS, is there a recommended and/or compatible antivirus software and/or tool one can use to increase the security of the system. The point being, if there is a malware on the system, all the security Tor provides could be in vain. Is Tail in anyway safer to use, having its own OS in the sense of malware presence on the system OS?

Comment: Alos, Make attention with your BIOS maybe infected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you download and burn Tails from a known virus-free computer, running Tails is much more secure that just adding an anti-virus software.

Tails does not only protect against virus, software keyloggers and similar that may be present on the system OS installed on your computer, but Tails also prevent many possible information leaks Tor Browser cannot protect against (e.g. leaks from other applications on your system).

About anti-virus software, be careful! Some anti-virus software leaks what files you have on your computer (e.g. files you downloaded through Tor Browser) to the company behind the anti-virus software. This is especially true if the anti-virus software uses cloud technology. Check the settings and privacy policy carefully.

Remove all malware:
Do a complete format and reinstall of your computer, using CD/DVDs you already got/burnt.

Avoid malware:
Do not install any untrusted software or games on your computer (e.g. downloaded from warez sites or bittorrent). If you OS tells you a file may be a virus, assume it is. AdBlock Plus plugin to Firefox helps a lot.

Comment: Could you suggest some of less hostile antivirus software to be used with TBB. Or you may suggest not to use Antivirus software at all, meaning cost, benefit equation of antivirus softwares do not justify their use.

Comment: If you are at all unsure/afraid you may get virus on your computer, you should use an antivirus software. If you have virus on your computer, it is as you said, no security/anonymity can any longer be guaranteed. I cannot suggest any however, since I don't use them. Someone else have to help you here with recommendations.