# Is it safe to run Avast with Tor

Tags: anonymity, security

Is it safe to run Avast with Tor?

I currently use Avast, but I've understood that Avast, as other anti-virus programs, send and log a lot of data about any browser that is being used. Are there some settings that need to be changed in order to run Avast safely with Tor or are other anti-virus programs considered safer (and if so, which?). How are anti-virus programs in general used with Tor or are they used at all? I could not find anything about this topic at the Tor Project's site.

Comment: You might find some useful information here https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/is-there-a-recommended-and-or-compatible-antivirus-software-and-or-tool-availabl I don't have the perfect answer to your question but running Tor on a system that is infected with viruses, spyware, malware etc will leave you in an even worse position than running AV. You can turn a lot of settings in Avast AV off including the 'real time protection' (web & file shields etc) but I'm not sure what point you would be making your machine too vulnerable.